# loadFeeds not woking when back to page in angularness

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

We are developing mobile app using `ng-Cordova`. We need get data from server when page load.So we write getting code in `loadFeeds`.example
page1:-

```
.controller('HomeSecondCtrl', function($scope,$http,$location,$window,$stateParams,$ionicHistory,$ionicActionSheet,BlankService,BlankFactory) {   
 $scope.loadFeeds();
     $scope.loadFeeds = function () {
            alert("Start");//getting code
          }
    $scope.toggleImage = function (index) {
        $location.path("/page2");
     }
    })
```

page2:-

```
.controller('SelectCategoryCtrl', function($scope,$location,$ionicHistory,$window,$http,$ionicActionSheet,BlankService) {
             $scope.back = function (){
           $location.path("/page1");
            }
         })
```

When app load we calld page1. So alert Will show `alert("Start");`. Then we have one button action `toggleImage`. Using this we redriect to page2 upto this ever thing fine.

our problem is

Second page have back button so using that we redirect to first page. But now `Alert not showing`. `loadFeeds not working`. Please guide us why loadFeeds is not working when are back to page1 from page2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(){
  $scope.loadFeeds();
});
```

`$ionicView.enter` : The view has fully entered and is now the active view.
This event will fire, whether it was the first load or a cached view.

Hope it helps.